# How to click the link to download the file in folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, webforms

I need to download the file in the folder that I saved all my files into it by showing the filename and click them

This is my code(I program by C# ASP.NET Webform)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"));
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        Response.Write(@"<a href=FileExplorer.aspx?file=" + file.Name.ToString() + "'\">" + file.Name.ToString() + "</a><br />");
    }

    Response.End();
}
```

}

Comment: Please be clearer. It is not obvious what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to use "FileExplorer.aspx" (maybe a good reason). I see 2 scenarios:

A) You don't need "FileExplorer.aspx" (i.e.: the user can directly download the file). In that case, I would change your line to

```
Response.Write(@"<a href='" + file.Name.ToString() + "'">" + file.Name.ToString() + "</a><br />");
```

B) You need FileExplorer because you put some logic in it (i.e.: authorization checks). In that case, direct links should be on the page and not the previous.

C) You are only listing available file that can be downloaded throughFileExplorer. I would create the list as you do in order to send a file ID in querystring to FileExplorer, and in FileExplorer I put the direct link (surounded with necessary logic if any)

Hope this helps
Serge

Comment: I must upload a file in an HTML page, after that, I send this file to another aspx page and save it into a folder APP_DATA. Subsequently, I show all those files in FileExplorer. That's why I need FileExplorer. And my code only shows filenames but cannot download them.